# Android LiveData Modification prob

Tags: android, arraylist, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I want to show a product list in my Android Application using Android new Architecture components. I have a Pojo class named `Products` like below:

```
public class Products {

    private List<ProductDetails> products = null;
    private Integer onSaleCount;
    private Integer total;
    private Integer page;
.........................
}
```

The webservice returns the list with pagination:

```
@GET("/products/")
Call<Products> getProducts(@Query("page") int page)
```

So each product list call, I am getting one set products list with other data.
I have already defined method to call the same in `ProductListRepository`:

```
public class ProductListRepository {
    @Inject
    ProductService mProductService;

    public Products getProductList(int pageNo) {
      .......................
      ..................
    }
}
```

But I am facing problem to set the LiveData in `ProductViewModel` because I want to merge the List of `ProductDetails` with older one and also update the value of the other variables in `Products` like `onSaleCount`, `pageNo`.

```
public class ProductListViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final ProductListRepository mProductListRepository;
private MediatorLiveData<Products> mProducts;

   public void getProductList(int pageNo) {

    Products products = mProductListRepository.getProductList(pageNo);
    if(products==null){
       mProducts.setValue(products);
    }else{
       // **How to add old List and new List and set it to LiveData**
    }
    return mProducts;
 }
```

}

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the idea behind to use `MediatorLiveData` there? It is not clear from the code.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja I think to modify the LiveData, I need MediatorLiveData. If it not required, please let me know the solution.

Comment: to only modify, `MutableLiveData` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just modify data, `mProducts` can be `MutableLiveData<Products>`, and your code like this:

```
public void getProductList(int pageNo) {

  Products products = mProductListRepository.getProductList(pageNo);
  if (products == null) {
     // Nothing to do, no new data
  } else {
    Products oldProducts = mProducts.getValue();
    // merge oldProducts and products into newProducts, as you prefer
    mProducts.setValue(newProducts);
  }
}
```

`MediatorLiveData` is designed to observe multiple `LiveData` sources.